# How to Run files and open folders as an administrater 11.10

Tags: kernel, root, users, administration, administrator

**Solved!!!**

**Enable open as administrator in nautilus!**

To get started, press Ctrl – Alt – T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

enter code here

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-gksu
```

[image]

After installing that application run copy and paste the line below and press enter.

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/
```

[image]

Finally, log out and back in then go and test it, by clicking your right mouse click on the file you want to run as Admin and your see a popup menu with the words: open as administrater.

[image]

Visit: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/add-open-as-administrator-to-nautilus-context-menu-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/ for help and from here.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much easer to open terminal and type in

```
gksu nautilus
```

this will open up root nautilus, letting you move, copy, and edit protected files.